# CRM 2011 UR 18 Issue - Cannot Render Report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

Getting this error (in the Application EventLog) when trying to display a particular report:

Exception message: The base class includes the field 'reportViewer', but its type (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer) is not compatible with the type of control (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer).

We have this in web.config for CRM:

```html
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
...
      <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

We're seeing an error on some machines, but not others.

This CRM machine has the `Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package` installed.  As I noted in the title, we have CRM 2011, UR 18.

Is there a different version of Report View that we need to install here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to resolve this issue.  We had to install the Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime onto the CRM web server, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747.

Microsoft had modified the PublicKeyToken for v2012 (which is version 11.0.0.0), so the resulting web.config edit also was more than just a version change.

The resulting, correct, CRMWeb web.config (for CRM 2011) is:

```
 <httpHandlers>
  <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
<compilation defaultLanguage="C#" debug="false">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Crm, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Crm.Platform.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```